# How can I get the logo to be responsive in my Wordpress theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive, graphical-logo

The logo on my website www.rodharbinson.com is not responsive, so when viewed on a mobile phone is far too big and covers the menu and header. The rest of the theme is responsive.

I've tried all the administrative theme settings and some custom CSS codes, with no joy.

Grateful for any suggestions for a possible fix.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please take time to review the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section, in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Your question should include the relevant code in a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with details of the exact error or problem, and details of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily control size of your logo for different screens using css media-queries,
Use the following css code in your theme to make the logo small for devices with width less then 480px

```
@media (max-width:480px){

    #logo img{
        width: 60px;
        height: auto;
    }

}
```

Change the width of logo according to your requirements.